# Calculate the power of double number in MIPS

Tags: mips

I have tried to write the code that will calculate the power of the double number recursively. But I do not get the wanted output. My output is Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000
. Here I got base numbers from loop1 and power from loop2. In power function, if the power is 0, the loop will return 1.

```
.data
array1: .double 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 4.2 5.0 2.0 0.0 0.0
array2:  .word 5 4 2 1 0 2 3 0 10
array_size: .word 9 
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
one: .double 1.0
.text

main:
    la $s1 array1
    la $s2 array2
    lw $s3 array_size #s3 = 9
    
    li $s4, 0
loop: 
    bge $s4 $s3 exit 

    l.d $f14 0($s1)
    lw $a2 0($s2)
    
    jal power
    
    li $v0, 3           
        mov.d $f12, $f20   
        syscall             

    addi $s1 $s1 8  
    addi $s2 $s2 4  
    
    addi $s4, $s4, 1 #index
    
    j loop
power: 
    andi $sp 0xfffffff8 
    addi $sp $sp -16
    s.d $f20 ($sp)  
    sw $ra 8($sp)
        s.d $f14, 8($sp)
        
    l.d $f20 one
    beq $a2 $zero done
    
    addi $a2 $a2 -1
    jal power
    
    mul.d $f20 $f14 $f20
    
done:
    l.d $f14, 8($sp)
    lw $ra 8($sp)
    l.d $f20 ($sp)
    addi $sp $sp 16
    jr $ra  
    
exit: 
    li $v0, 10         
    syscall
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!, I changed to `s.d $f20 8($sp)` and  `s.d $f14, 16($sp)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same stack slot for both `$f20` and `$f14`.

One slot can only hold one value.  Since that code doesn't otherwise use `$f20`, simply remove save & restore of that.

However, you're saving and restoring `$f14` for the benefit of the caller, which is incorrect.  That is a scratch register (call-clobbered) and it should be saved & restored for your own function body's benefit.

That means that the restore of `$f14` should go before the multiplication rather than as part of epilogue.

The multiplication should apply to `$f0` and `$f14`, leaving the result in `$f0`, and at such a time that `$f14` is restored.